# ServiceStack XML Service how remove BOM character?

Tags: xml, web-services, servicestack, byte-order-mark

It is possible to disable the BOM for ServiceStack services such as XML?

Comment: ServiceStack responds to client applications, you can't edit that in notepad, or anything else, for the client application gets the response. :\